# whatsapp api request code not executing and not returning a request code

Tags: php, exception, whatsapp

I am trying to implement the [whatsAPI](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI) but I always get this error 
"*There was a problem trying to request the code*".
Here is the full error that is showing in my console:

```
####start of error notice#####

[12-Mar-2013 22:44:59] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$reason in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whatsapp/test/whatsprot.class.php on line 1268
[12-Mar-2013 22:44:59] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'There was a problem trying to request the code.' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whatsapp/test/whatsprot.class.php:1269
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whatsapp/test/test.php(36): WhatsProt->checkCredentials()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whatsapp/test/whatsprot.class.php on line 1269

####end of error notice#####
```

these are my credentials for initializing the class

```
$userPhone = '8801770648732';       
$userIdentity = '352264050503669';                                               
$userName = 'shishir';          
$destinationPhone = '8801713206053';                                                
$debug = TRUE;
$whatsapp = new WhatsProt($userPhone, $userIdentity, $userName, $debug);
```

and for the requesting a requestCode

```
$service_type = "sms";    
$country_code = "BD";    
$language_code = "en";    
$request_code = $whatsapp->requestCode($service_type, $country_code, $language_code);
```

Every time it stuck at the  `$whatsapp->requestCode` with that error. 
I'm not sure what i am doing wrong . 
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I also need answer to this question

Comment: me too............

Answer (score -1):

It's look like you don't have curl extension. 
This Exception is thrown by `checkCredentials` method.

Check if your phpinfo shows curl.

Comment: Lacking cURL should show a very, very clear error message. I doubt this is the case here.